# Marketing Cloud - Unable to store the data into DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, cloudpage

I have created a survey page, question and answers(radio button) are retriving from data extension and displaying on a cloud page. On submitting the answers, values are not storing in data extension. Please assist me on the error.

```
%%[
var @Name, @ActID, @Question,@Answer,@SurveyName
SET @Name = RequestParameter("N")
set @ActID = RequestParameter("e")
set @Question = RequestParameter('Question')
set @Answer = RequestParameter('Answer')
set @SurveyName = 'Color'
set @Date = NOW()
set @rowsToReturn = 2000 /* up to 2000 */

<form action="%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%" method="post">
set @rows1 = LookupOrderedRows("Survey_Question" ,@rowsToReturn, "Question asc", "Survey_Name","Color")

set @prevQuestion = ""
for @i = 1 TO RowCount(@rows1) DO

  set @row1 = Row(@rows1,@i)
  set @RowQuestion = Field(@row1, "Question")

  if empty(@prevQuestion) or @RowQuestion != @prevQuestion then

     set @prevQuestion = @RowQuestion

]%%

    <h1>%%=v(@RowQuestion)=%%</h1>
<br>

%%[     
    /* Looking options for a question */
    set @rows = LookupRows('Survey_Question','Question',@RowQuestion)
    for @j = 1 TO RowCount(@rows) DO
        set @row = row(@rows, @j)
        set @RowAnswer = Field(@row, "Answer")
]%%
 <input type="radio" id="%%=v(@RowAnswer)=%%" name="%%=v(@RowQuestion)=%%" value="%%=v(@RowAnswer)=%%">
<label for="%%=v(@RowAnswer)=%%">%%=v(@RowAnswer)=%%</label><br>
     <br>
%%[ next @j ]%%

%%[ endif ]%%

%%[ next @i ]%%

%%[  if RequestParameter("submitted") == "submitted" then
    

set @createDeRecord = InsertData( 'Survey_Response_1',
   'Account_ID', @ActID,
   'Question',@Question,
   'Answer',@Answer,
   'Date', @Date)

   endif
]%%
<input type="submit" value="Submit">




%%=IIF(RequestParameter("submitted") == "submitted", '<p>Your form has been submitted.</p>','')=%%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a quite complex solution that you have come up with to grab questions and answers from a DE dynamically and to set all input names dynamically as well.

What is missing in your script, is the same mechanism that you used for grabbing questions and answers, which would dynamically iterate through all possible input names on form submission and grab the data that has been submitted.

You had this in your code:

```
set @Question = RequestParameter('Question')
set @Answer = RequestParameter('Answer')
```

But you don't have inputs called '`Question`' and '`Answer`' in your form - instead, you are dynamically populating input names based on what is in your DE, that's why it wasn't working.

I've also reorganized your script, but it could still be improved so I suggest a clean-up once you get this up and running.
I'm not sure why you need the `@prevQuestion` variable, but I left it in there just in case I missed something.

Here's the overall logic that should work:

```
%%[
SET @Name = RequestParameter("N")
set @ActID = RequestParameter("e")
set @SurveyName = 'Color'
set @Date = NOW()
set @rowsToReturn = 2000 /* up to 2000 */
set @rows1 = LookupOrderedRows("Survey_Question" ,@rowsToReturn, "Question asc", "Survey_Name","Color")
set @prevQuestion = ""
set @submitted = RequestParameter("submitted")

if @submitted == 'true' then

for @k = 1 TO RowCount(@rows1) DO

  set @rowk = Row(@rows1,@k)
  set @RowQuestion = Field(@rowk, "Question")
  set @submittedAnswer = RequestParameter(@RowQuestion)

  if @k == 1 then
  set @q = @RowQuestion
  set @a = @submittedAnswer
  else
  set @q = concat(@q," ,",@RowQuestion)
  set @a = concat(@a," ,",@submittedAnswer)
  endif

next @k

  set @createDeRecord = InsertData('Survey_Response_1',
   'Account_ID', @ActID,
   'Question',@q,
   'Answer',@a,
   'Date', @Date)

]%%

Your form has been submitted.

%%[

else

]%%
<form action="%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%" method="post">
%%[


for @i = 1 TO RowCount(@rows1) DO

  set @row1 = Row(@rows1,@i)
  set @RowQuestion = Field(@row1, "Question")

  if empty(@prevQuestion) or @RowQuestion != @prevQuestion then

     set @prevQuestion = @RowQuestion
]%%

    <h1>%%=v(@RowQuestion)=%%</h1>
<br>
%%[     
    /* Looking options for a question */
    set @rows = LookupRows('Survey_Question','Question',@RowQuestion)
    for @j = 1 TO RowCount(@rows) DO
    set @row = row(@rows, @j)
    set @RowAnswer = field(@row,"Answer")
]%%

   <input type="radio" id="%%=v(@RowAnswer)=%%" name="%%=v(@RowQuestion)=%%" value="%%=v(@RowAnswer)=%%">
<label for="%%=v(@RowAnswer)=%%">%%=v(@RowAnswer)=%%</label><br>
     <br>
  
%%[ next @j ]%%
  
%%[ endif ]%%

%%[ next @i ]%%  
  
  
<input name="submitted" type="hidden" value="true"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
%%[endif]%%
```

Comment: Hello @zuzannamj , Thanks for the updated code, it is storing duplicate values, if there are 2 questions and 4 answers , it is inserting  8 records into DE. Thanks In Advance

Comment: See my updated answer, I've taken out the insert data function out of the loop and used a concat to concatenate all q&a into strings so that they get stored in one row. I'm sure you'll be able to take it from there and modify further as needed.

Comment: Many Thanks @Zuzannamj